# Mysql: order by priority in WHERE LIKE Condition

Tags: mysql, left-join, sql-order-by, sql-like

I want to get all products with following conditions
1. Product name Like "decor"
2. List all products from category with category name Like "decor"

Here is my sql query

```
param = "decor"
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT
P.ProductName,P.ProductPrice FROM
Products_Joined AS P LEFT JOIN Categories_Products_Link AS CP ON
P.ProductId = CP.ProductId LEFT JOIN Categories ON CP.CategoryID =
Categories.CategoryID where P.ProductName LIKE '%" & param &"%' OR
Categories.CategoryName LIKE '%" & param &"%' order by P.ProductName "
```

My query is working fine and I have returned an out put like this

[image]

But I want the result as 
[image]

Need to order by Product name like

How can I do it?

Comment: Your query does not remotely match your current output which you showed us.  Please show us the actual query/results.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: What is the logic behind this ordering?  I'd guess that you want to sort `3-Drawer Chest` as `Drawer Chest`, without the leading number and dash.  Are there any other types of data which would require special sorting rules?

Comment: No, My search term is "decor". I want to display the product name starts with decor as first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN P.ProductName LIKE 'Decor%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    P.ProductName;
```

This would put all products whose name start with `Decor` first, followed by all other products.  Within each of those two groups, we continue to sort alphabetically by the whole product name.

I can offer the following full query:

```
SELECT
    t.ProductName, t.ProductPrice
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        p.ProductName, p.ProductPrice
    FROM Products_Joined AS P
    LEFT JOIN Categories_Products_Link AS cp
        ON p.ProductId = cp.ProductId
    LEFT JOIN Categories c
        ON cp.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
    WHERE
        p.ProductName LIKE '%param%' OR
        c.CategoryName LIKE '%param%'
) t
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN t.ProductName LIKE 'Decor%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    t.ProductName;
```

Comment: It return empty rows

Comment: @JancyAbraham Not possible.  An `ORDER BY` clause does not affect the result set, only the order of the rows.  Your query has some other problem.  Just remove `ORDER BY` completely and you will still get zero rows.

Comment: When I remove the ORDER BY clause I got 4 rows. 
ORDER BY P.ProductName is working

Comment: You're going to need to make this problem reproducible.  As already mentioned, _ORDER BY cannot control the number of rows in the result set_.

Comment: The ORDER BY CASE is working when I remove the DISTINCT.

Comment: Right...didn't see that.  I think you can't order by something which does not appear in the select list if you use distinct.  The issue is that the query was failing, not that it returned zero records.

Comment: @JancyAbraham I edited my question to give you a full query which should run without error.  I think the issue with you seeing zero rows was that the query was failing.  The option I gave you should at least run.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a function

```
 DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS PatIndex;
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE FUNCTION PatIndex(pattern VARCHAR(255), tblString VARCHAR(255)) 
 RETURNS INTEGER
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

DECLARE i INTEGER;
SET i = 1;

myloop: WHILE (i <= LENGTH(tblString)) DO

    IF SUBSTRING(tblString, i, 1) REGEXP pattern THEN
        RETURN(i);
        LEAVE myloop;        
    END IF;    

    SET i = i + 1;

   END WHILE; 

   RETURN(0);

   END
```

Then use this as your sort logic

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
P.ProductName,P.ProductPrice FROM
Products_Joined AS P LEFT JOIN Categories_Products_Link AS CP ON
P.ProductId = CP.ProductId LEFT JOIN Categories ON CP.CategoryID =
Categories.CategoryID where P.ProductName LIKE '%" & param &"%' OR
Categories.CategoryName LIKE '%" & param &"%'                           
 order by   SUBSTRING(P.ProductName ,PATINDEX('[A-z]',P.ProductName ),length(P.ProductName ) - PATINDEX('[A-z]',P.ProductName )+1)
```

Comment: No I have executed this substring query in mysql, also the patindex exist in ms sql server.